# Firebase's onMessageReceived is called only once and not called after that

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the web server delivers a message, the app calls once, but after that, onMessageReceived is not called. What am I missing? I sent it with the same content

This is my Code

```
    @PostMapping("/send/token")
    public String sendToToken() throws FirebaseMessagingException {

        Message message = Message.builder()
                .setToken(FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN)
                .setNotification(Notification.builder()
                        .setTitle("Message")
                        .setBody("send message to you")
                        .build())
                .build();

        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);

        return response;
    }
```

Result
response result : true

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage msg) {
        Log.d("msg : ", msg.toString());
        if (msg.getData().isEmpty()) {
            showNotificationMessage(msg.getNotification().getTitle(), msg.getNotification().getBody()); 
        } else {
            showDataMessage(msg.getData().get("title"), msg.getData().get("content"));
        }
        super.onMessageReceived(msg);
    }
```

Comment: I solved this problem. However, it was solved by project regeneration